# Abstract formulation of the Arzela Ascoli Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, arzela-ascoli

In some paper I read, it says we may use the abstract version of the Arzela Ascoli theorem to conclude for some sequence $f_k: I \times \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, $I$ some interval, that

$f_k(t) \rightarrow f(t) \ \ \ \text{in} \ C_\text{loc}(\mathbb{R}^n),\ \text{uniformly in } t \in I. $

Unfortunately, I don't know such a generalized version of the theorem. Thus I wonder, what has to be shown to conclude this. Is it just uniform boundedness and equicontinuity, both uniformly in $t$? Or does this require some more special conditions? Thank you for any hints.

Comment: An abstract version is mentioned in [Nonlinear Partial Differential Equations and Related Topics: Dedicated to Nina N. Uraltseva](https://books.google.ie/books?id=80zVAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA245&lpg=PA245&dq=%22abstract+version+of+the+Arzela+Ascoli+theorem%22&source=bl&ots=j4A-HY3qfl&sig=ULd4ZAXzfDKPUpQsXrG0_2sWSU8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjzmuHQi5PcAhUIAcAKHZH5AYsQ6AEIPTAC#v=onepage&q=%22abstract%20version%20of%20the%20Arzela%20Ascoli%20theorem%22), on pages 245-246.

Is it a typo that $n$ is both the subscript of the function and the dimension of the codomain?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I can't read the whole theorem in this preview. And the $n$ is indeed a typo, I'll just correct it, thanks.